# What job don't students like very much?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, questions, negation

I need to have my English students read a pie chart containing information about jobs. One of the questions I wrote is:

> *"What job don't students like very much?"*

(They are expected to read the chart and say "doctor," which was voted by two students only).

Now, is that question grammatically correct? I just find it awkward. I know there are more natural options, but that is the wording I need for non-native 6th graders. Thanks in advance! I apologize if you find this question too silly.

Comment: You might think that "Which of these jobs don't these students like very much?" is in a more formal register.

Comment: I definitely like you version better, Edwin. But still, is mine correct?

Comment: [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/what) gives: **what**  determiner
1. a. used with a noun in requesting further information about the identity or categorization of something: _what job does he do?_. It's grammatical. But I'd use 'What job does he do' as a cold question, but 'Which of these jobs don't these students like very much?' given an (especially short) list/subset to choose from, as in your 'question'.

Comment: Yours is correct. It is just the contraction does not sound natural. See the answer below for suggested rewrites

Comment: The "mistake" in your question, is "also" in the word *job*. The accepted answer talk abouts **Which ... jobs***.  Alternatives: "What (type of) job(s) **do** students **dislike** most?" OR "Which job do students like the least?" OR "Which is the most unpopular job for students?" OR "**Which job** is the least popular/ has the least number of votes?" etc.

Comment: If you leave the question as is: the answer could include two or more jobs the students don't like. You need a superlative in your question, in order to have just the *one* answer: "Which job (singular) ..... like the least?" as suggested by Avon, or any that I suggested above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's ok but maybe move the "not" and change "what" to "which"

> Which of the jobs do students not like very much?

or perhaps better

> Which of the jobs do students like the least?

Eplanation:

Removing the contraction "don't" to "do not" becomes "do not students like" which sounds wrong. It's very yoda speak.

"Which" is preferable to "What". It's not an open-ended question. They are being asked to select from a range of answers so "which" is more appropriate.

"Not like very much" vs "like the least". I think the latter is more accurate for the question. It is asking for THE least whereas the former could answer with a selection.

Comment: Thanks, Avon. Can you tell why? I feel like placing 'not' at the end, too, but cannot say why. Is there a rule or is it just about usage?

Comment: Sure I'll put explanations in edit

Comment: Do you not move words around regularly when you split up contractions in sentences like "don't you move words around regularly?" Why should this sentence be any different?

Comment: @PeterShor "What job do not students like?" I have not heard of this kind of student. I guess they're not students at all. ("not" sounds like an adjective before the noun like that.)